# Javascript Synchronous Event Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange issue regarding a series of tasks that need to run in a timed manner.

```js
if (str === "venuehours") {
  weekCommencing = $('#weekCommencing').val();
  venueId = $('#venueId').val();

  if (weekCommencing !== '') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#results-vhhours').addClass('show');
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#loaderModal').modal('hide');
    }, 2200);

    $("#results-content").load("/reportbuilder/VenueHours", {
      weekCommencing: weekCommencing,
      venueId: venueId
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#results-vhhours').offset().top
      }, 500, 'linear');
    }, 2300);
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#loaderModal').modal('hide');
    }, 2200);

    $('.rota-build-frm-er.error-msg').html('* Please select Week Commencing Date!');
  }
}
```

On our development server the above falls over as the data seems to take longer than the `setTimeout` functions allow, so the sequence doesn't work correctly.

This code was put together quickly as part of the prototype build and we know it needs refactoring to make it durable. We understand we need to restructure this code to allow the `load` function to be central to the synchronous tasks - and considered implementing promises as a solution - but not sure how we would implement in the below scenario?

Can anyone offer us a suggestion to push us down the correct path please? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Without seeing an actual working example of the problem (or at the very least the associated HTML and CSS so we can create one ourselves) we can't really recreate the issue in order to solve it. That said, my assumption would be that you need to use the callback of `load()` to run your logic only when the call completes

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you have a series of actions that need to be done sequentially, but they are firing out of order.

Consider using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and chaining the actions through promise chains. Notice I have altered the timeout values as they now only execute after the previous action is complete.

```
if (str === "venuehours") {
  weekCommencing = $('#weekCommencing').val();
  venueId = $('#venueId').val();

  if (weekCommencing !== '') {
    var action = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#results-vhhours').addClass('show');
        resolve();
      }, 2000);
    });
    action.then(function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#loaderModal').modal('hide');
          resolve();
        }, 200);
      });
    }).then(function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $("#results-content").load("/reportbuilder/VenueHours", {
          weekCommencing: weekCommencing,
          venueId: venueId
        }, function() {
          resolve();
        });
      });
    }).then(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#results-vhhours').offset().top
        }, 500, 'linear');
      }, 100);
    });
 } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#loaderModal').modal('hide');
    }, 2200);

    $('.rota-build-frm-er.error-msg').html('* Please select Week Commencing Date!');
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much for this - though we are still experiencing the same issue - not sure why - real head scratcher!

Comment: What exactly is happening and what do you want to happen? As Rory said, without some actual examples, its a bit difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve.